# How to use laravel voyager for two different admin url?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

Can i use laravel voyager for two different url admin?

> Sample Code

```
Route::prefix('admin-1')->group(function() {
     Voyager::routes();
});

Route::prefix('admin-2')->group(function() {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

I have tried this but the admin-2 always give me redirect to the admin-1 when login and execute menu in dashboard.

Comment: I don't think Voyager has this feature by default to have multiple admin prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider defining different access roles for users in the roles bread instead of a different url.

If that doesn't suit your needs, then it's better making your own admin panel.